# Items in Dynamodb are in value of undefined

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When I'm querying my dynamodb the returned Items have values of `undefined`. I haven't seen this before on Stackoverflow and I really don't know what's causing this. When I log the callback data object it returns this:

`{ Items: [ { username: [Object], password: [Object] } ],
  Count: 1,
  ScannedCount: 1 }`

I really don't know why this is as I entered String values and query for String values as well. If needed I can add the query Params and the entry data as well as the DescribeTable return data object.

Comment: Yes the response object is a JSON object. You need to get the data from Items object.

Comment: @notionquest yep that was it. Figured it out just a few minutes before, thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query API will return the output as JSON. The data will be present on Items array object.

```
Items — (Array<map<map>>)
```

[Query API Response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

Comment: good input, hope this might be helpful for others as i haven't seen this before.